# Laravel Class 'HASH' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

after validate rules i want to check current enterd password width saved hash password on database.and i'm using this below code, but i get error :

Error Code:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException

Class 'HASH' not found
```

my Controller Action:

```
public function update($id)
{
    $rules = array(
        'name'       => 'required|alpha',
        'family'     => 'required',
        'email'      => 'required',
        'password'   => 'required|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation'=>'required',
    );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('/admin/profile')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    } 
    else 
    {
        $currentPassword = User::find($id);
        if ( $currentPassword == HASH::make(Input::get('currpassword')) ){
            return Redirect::route('/admin/profile')
                ->with('message', 'Password Match Error')
                ->withInput();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be `Hash::make`, not `HASH::make`.

Answer (score 26):

I also faced this issue. But finally found the fix for the issue. Please include the following path on top of your code file. Then it may fix.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
```

Answer (score 1):

in your controller file add in top

```
use Hash
// and use Hash::make instead of HASH::make
Hash::make(Input::get('currpassword'))
```